# jQuery problem within clicking on page

Tags: toggleclass, jquery

Ok, I am using this jQuery here:

```
$('html').click(function(){
    if ($(".trigger").hasClass("active"))
    {
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
});

$(".panel").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
    });
});
```

Ok, so a reply stated that I should visit another answer, have tried this, but this only works on the first try.  If I show click on the trigger again after that than click on anywhere in the page, it doesn't work again.  It fails to hide it all of the time when it is visible.  How can I fix this?

So, when the panel gets displayed, I'd like to be able to click outside of the panel to hide it again for everytime that it gets displayed.  I would like to have the opportunity to ONLY be able to click on the class="trigger" object in order to display and hide the class="panel" object by either clicking on the class="trigger" object again, or clicking outside of the class="panel" object anywhere on the page.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: Have seen his question and answer, but this only works on the first try, doesn't work after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.panel').hide();

$(document).click(function(e){
    var $t = $(e.target);
    if($t.is('.trigger *,.trigger')){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $t.closest('.trigger').toggleClass("active");
    } else if(!$t.is('.panel *,.panel')){
        $(".panel").hide("fast");
        $('.trigger.active').removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fU3v/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can stop event propagation in the `click` handler you register on the trigger, then register another `click` handler on the `html` element and use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to determine if the panel is hidden or not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $("html").click(function() {
        var $panel = $(".panel:visible");
        if ($panel.length) {
            $panel.hide("fast");
            $(".trigger").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @SoLoGHoST, you're right, there were mismatched parenthesis in my code. That's fixed now. Thanks for the heads-up :)